# Android Emulator with GPU enabled not working

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, gpu

i am struggling for days with getting the Android Studio Emulator working with Emulated Performance to Automatic/Hardware.
I always run into these errors:

```
Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not create GLES 2.x Pbuffer! Emulator: 
Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string! Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer 
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it. 
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Now i don´t know if its a hardware issue that the server is only running a onboard GPU which regarding to Intel should allow OpenGL up to 4.3

Some more information machine i am trying to get this running

```
[root@CentOS-74-64-minimal bin]# glxinfo name of display: :1 display: :1 screen: 0 direct rendering: Yes server glx vendor string: SGI server glx version string: 1.4
[root@CentOS-74-64-minimal bin]# glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.0.2
```

I really appreciate any help. I tried nearly everything the last days without luck, from upgrading OS/Kernel until trying different graphic card drivers.

Comment: I'm guessing your BIOS setup has accelerated virtualization off

Comment: Its a dedicated root server running in a datacenter. Is there a way to quickly check if its on/off through ssh without restarting in some rescue console to look into bios?

Comment: Sounds like a powerful machine, but that setting still may be off, and even more probably being a server because it doesn't need to simulate anything

Comment: Don't think so, You need to shut it down

Comment: Virtualization: VT-x. Thats what it says for "lscpu" command.

Comment: It appears to be on, so, I have no clue. Sorry.

Comment: Yeah like said i am looking for almost a week now whats the problem.

Comment: Have you tried installing different compatible (or latest drivers) for the onbaord gfx card.

Comment: @romu What does: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-linux say?

Comment: Did you install KVM as @Morrison Chang is pointing out?

Comment: Yeah tried different drivers. Might be a problem with Android Studio and the Emulator it self or that i am connected through a remote session? I know OpenGl is not possible through a default VNC session but if this would be the problem i guess the error messes would say something different?

Comment: I installed KVM following the docs here: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-kvm-hypervisor-on-centos-7-and-rhel-7/.  But actually i don´t want to create a virtual machine if not even the Software is running on the root machines hardware? I don´t understand. I followed the installation steps here until step 2) start virt-manager. Otherwise the CPU seems to support virtualization as its outputting "vmx". What now?

Comment: [root@CentOS-74-64-minimal opt]# glxinfo | grep -i opengl 
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.0.1. ES 2.0 saying here but https://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/2789/hd-graphics-530 until 4.4

Comment: well, how did you think the **emulator** works? It runs in a virtual machine.You should have stated in the question that your environment is not the usual. I don't understand why you asked this if you already know you can't run OpenGL through VNC.

Comment: @Chisko. I mentioned this only for the purpose that i am already aware of the problematic with running OpenGL Software through a remote session. However this should not be the problem as you can use X11vnc for e.g. So the environment i guess is not as unusual as you might think. I am sure there are lots of use cases where you want/need to run the android emulator not on your local machine, but not sure why it fails here. If the hardware supports OpenGL as already figured out i would like to understand why the emulator is throwing such errors and how to solve this.

Comment: Otherwise i would also appreciate any other possible solutions to emulate some android device on my own server where Google Play Store is build in. I don't understand why i am even forced to use hardware GPU emulation. Software emulation the emulator works fine for me but like said there is no Google Play Store Support.